# Worried about changing jobs with the need for accommodations

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job, negotiation, disability

I am considering interviewing for another company. At my current job I have a standing desk which I need for my health. I was able to get this desk after providing supporting medical documentation. A standing desk is very important to me. Should I inquiry of a standing desk option during the interview? During the interview process with the Human Resources manager? Or with the department managers? What if, for some reason I never have contact with a HR rep, when is an appropriate time to raise my inquiry? Up front during the first interview? Only after I receive an offer? On my first day in the office?

Additionally, does this accommodation present a weakness on my side of a negotiation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not a good idea to ask for it during your first interview. It would cast a doubt on your priorities. It can always be discussed between the period once the offer has been done and your first day of joining.

I don't think companies straight away refuse something which makes the employee feel comfortable and productive.

So, **don't ask or discuss about it in the first interview**.

Comment: If it's an absolute sine qua non, you can bring it up after you get the offer (I'd love to, but I have one concern...:) ___However___, I'd like to point out that any desk can be made a standing desk by putting a suitable box, or a board on stacked books, or something similar, so it isn't entirely clear to me that you can't solve this yourself

Comment: @keshlam a makeshift standing desk like that may well not be acceptable within the OH&S standards of a large company.

Comment: Granted, though I've seen a lot of workstation kludges over the years, some of them supporting  seventy-pound (weight) crt monitors.

Comment: @NathanCooper Yes, after the interview and before you sign the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The initial interview is not the right time unless you are specifically asked a question about that., Once you start it's too late if they're not going to accommodate you, asking earlier also means the desk should be there day 1.

The right time to ask is at the offer stage, ideally if they contact you to say they will be making an offer you could raise it then.

Finally no it's definitely not a weakness especially if you have medical evidence to support you i.e. it's a necessity not just a preference.